# Error al subir imagen destacada en wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-imagenes

Hola amigos espero que estén bien. Estoy aprendiendo wordpress y estoy atascado en la parte de subir imágenes destacadas. Ya tengo agregada la siguiente función en el archivo functions.php :

```
if (function_exists('add_theme_support')) {
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');      
}
```

Lo anterior me habilita la opción de subir imagen destacada. Sin embargo cuando selecciono la imagen me da un error. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ese es el error que me sale. Alguien le ha pasado eso? 
de ser así, cómo lo solucionó?
De antemano gracias.

Comment: Debes meter ese código dentro de una función _setup_ y luego _engancharla_ a `after_setup_theme`. EN este enlace un ejemplo claro de lo que debes hacer https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/after_setup_theme/#user-contributed-notes

Comment: Puede ser un error del archivo, abre el jpg en photoshop o algun otro editor y guardala nuevamente como jpg o png e intenta subirla nuevamente